# Explode Pandas column of list of dictionaries into additional columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
   id  type  length  parsed    
0  1   A     144     [{'key1':'value1'},{'key1':'value2', 'key2':'value3'},...]
1  1   B     20      [{'key1':'value4'},{'key2':'value5'},...]
2  4   A     54      [{'key3':'value6'},...]
```

As you can see, the `parsed` column is a list of dictionaries. Sometimes, the dictionaries in the list could have multiple instances of the same key (for example in the first row, multiple `key1`). What I want to do is explode this column into multiple columns, so this df would become something like this:

```
   id  type  length  key1             key2     key3
0  1   A     144     [value1,value2]  value3
1  1   B     20      value4           value5
2  4   A     54                                value6
```

Is there a way to do this? I

Comment: Is `[value1, value2]` in output a `list` or `string`?

Comment: Honestly, it could be either. I would prefer a list but don't have a strong preference.

Comment: I guess the answer given by @anky should work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate further but the basic idea is create a dataframe from the parsed column and aggregate as list and join back:

```
s = df['parsed'].explode()

(df.join(pd.DataFrame(s.tolist(),index=s.index)
.groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: x.dropna().tolist())))
```

---

```
  id type  length                                             parsed  \
0   1    A     144  [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key1': 'value2', 'key2'...   
1   1    B      20           [{'key1': 'value4'}, {'key2': 'value5'}]   
2   4    A      54                               [{'key3': 'value6'}]   

               key1      key2      key3  
0  [value1, value2]  [value3]        []  
1          [value4]  [value5]        []  
2                []        []  [value6]
```